# Trading View Custom Session Issue

Tags: python, reactjs, node.js, tradingview-api, trading

I am using trading View Charting Library I am using saudi stock exchange data, i am having an issue, In TradingView default week start from Monday but in Saudi Arabia Week start from Sunday so i dont know how to set session that starts the week from Sunday to Thursday